# Unable to add firewall rule to local GPO using new-getfirewallrule

Tags: powershell, firewall

I'm trying to add firewall rule using New-NetFirewallRule cmdlet. By default the rule is added to local FW. As per this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps
to add the rule to local GPO, PolicyStore parameter needs to be set with either hostname or localhost parameter.

However when I try the command : New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "testing" -PolicyStore localhost  ,
I get this error :

"New-NetFirewallRule : The network name cannot be found.
At line:1 char:1
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "testing" -PolicyStore localhost
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [New-NetFir
ewallRule], CimException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 67,New-NetFirewallRule"

Comment: Did you find the solution ?
I'm using **netsh**: `netsh advfirewall>set store=COMPUTERNAME` => https://pastebin.com/hvVU61wv

Answer (score 0):

Set-NetFirewallRule : Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1

- Set-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "File And Printer Sharing" -Enabled ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (MSFT_NetFirewallRule:root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetFirewallRule) [Set-Ne
  tFirewallRule], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 5,Set-NetFirewallRule
  ```

Comment: Could You improve formatting a bit, your code bleeds out in the whitespace and explain what you are doing to highlight what the problem is instead of just dumping the answer will make it a much more useful answer for the indexing and future use :)